# Time Series plot grouped values in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following grouped dataset:

```
dataset.groupby(['Date',"Product"]).count()
```

```
                        Product Code      Description
Date         Product
2019-01-03     A            1              1
               B            3              3 
               C            NaN            NaN
2019-01-04     A            8              8
               B            NaN            NaN 
               C            NaN            NaN
2019-01-11     A            NaN            NaN
               B            4              4
               C            5              5
```

The dataset groups three products and counts the number of occurrences grouped by date and these products. Some date information might be missing, for example 2019-01-05.

I would like to create a timeseries plot, in which the missing data values are plotted as 0 and the products are plotted in a different color.

I have tried:

```
dataset.groupby(['Date',"Product"])["Product Code"].count().plot(lw=3,color="Main app code")
```

generating the error, that it is an invalid RGBA argument.

If I just try:

```
dataset.groupby(['Date',"Product"])["Product Code"].count().plot(lw=3)
```

The plot does plot only the dates, where information is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using:

```
dataset.groupby(['Date',"Product"])["Product Code"].count().fillna(0).plot(lw=3)
```

fillna(0) should replace NaN with 0.